# Error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

I was trying to create a file to save pictures from the camera, it turns out that I can't create the file.
But I really can't find the mistake. Can you have a look at it and give me some advice?

```
    private File createImageFile(){
            File imageFile=null;
            String stamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            File dir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String imageFileName="JPEG_"+stamp+"_";
            try {
                imageFile=File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",dir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("YJW",e.getMessage());
            }
            return  imageFile;
        }
```

And I have added the permission.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The method always gives such mistakes:

> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: The [example given in the API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) has this line: `// Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
        path.mkdirs();`. Are you sure the directory already exists?

Comment: Try this link: [android canvas save always java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605440/android-canvas-save-always-java-io-ioexception-open-failed-enoent-no-such-fil)

Comment: Thanks! In the training there isn't such a hint. I should have searched the API references. Thanks!

Comment: @JiaweiYang Was it my suggestion that worked? If so, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Because Android 10 (Api level 29) and higher doesnt allow to create a folder in external storage directly.. You should use getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The Pictures directory might not exist yet. It's not guaranteed to be there.

In [the API documentation for `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)), the code ensures the directory exists using `mkdirs`:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");

try {
    // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
    path.mkdirs();
```

...so it may be as simple as adding that `path.mkdirs()` to your existing code before you `createTempFile`.

Comment: required to check the new directory has been created or not by   if (!path.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("Un Available:" , path.getAbsolutePath());
            }

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(...) is depecratedString use this.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).toString(); instead

Answer (score 20):

when a user picks a file from the gallery, there is no guarantee that the file that was picked was added or edited by some other app. So, if the user picks on a file that let’s say belongs to another app we would run into the permission issues. A quick fix for that is to add this code in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest ... >
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**Note: For Android 11 refer Scope storage Enforcement Policy https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage**

Comment: It not works with API level 30, unfortunately

Comment: Android 11 the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag, Scope Storage Android 11 android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true" to Data Merge/Move. for more detail about scope storage please refer Link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage and https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

Comment: android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true" required for your existing APP when user update his/her android OS to 11. with this you can transfer data from your old DIR to New DIR W.R.T 11 Scope Storage Policy.

Answer (score 13):

Replace:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

With:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
```

make sure you call:

```
mkdirs() // and not mkdir()
```

Here's the code that should work for you:

```
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "whatever_directory_existing_or_not/sub_dir_if_needed/");
        storageDir.mkdirs(); // make sure you call mkdirs() and not mkdir()
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  // prefix
                ".jpg",         // suffix
                storageDir      // directory
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents

        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("our file", image.toString());
        return image;
    }
```

I had a bad experience following the example given in [Android Studio Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) and I found out that there are many others experiencing the same about this particular topic here in stackoverflow, that is because even if we set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

the problem persists in some devices.

My experience was that the example worked when I tried it in debug mode, after that 3 more tests it so happened that my SD suddenly was corrupted, but I don't think it has to do with their example (funny). I bought a new SD card and tried it again, only to realize that still both release and debug mode did the same error log: directory does not exist ENOENT. Finally, I had to create the directories myself whick will contain the captured pictures from my phone's camera. And I was right, it works just perfect.

I hope this helps you and others out there searching for answers.

Comment: It is not working for android 11

Answer (score 9):

A quick fix for that is to add this code in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest ... >
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Note: Applicable for API level 29 or Higher

Comment: this is a teporary sulution for API 29 only it will not work with API 30

Answer (score 5):

I used the contentResolver with the URI and it worked for me. Saw it in another SO post which i can't find.

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

hope it helps....

Answer (score 2):

I have solved like this:

```
        public Intent getImageCaptureIntent(File mFile) {
             Intent mIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", mFile);
             mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

             // The tip is this code below
             List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                 for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                      String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                      grantUriPermission(packageName, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                 }

             return  mIntent;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using kotlin then use below function.
you have to provide a path for storing image, a Bitmap (in this case a image) and if you want to decrease the quality of the image then provide %age i.e 50%.

```
fun cacheLocally(localPath: String, bitmap: Bitmap, quality: Int = 100) {
        val file = File(localPath)
        file.createNewFile()
        val ostream = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, ostream)
        ostream.flush()
        ostream.close()
    }
```

hope it will work.

Comment: kotlin or not does not matter here.

Answer (score 1):

```
File dirPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File imageFile = new File(dirPath, "YourPicture.jpg");

try {
    if(!dirPath.isDirectory()) {
       dirPath.mkdirs(); 
    } 
    imageFile.createNewFile();

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {  

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());  

    String imageFileName="JPEG_"+stamp+".jpg";  

    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  imageFileName);  

    return photo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error while saving Bitmap to External Directory and found a helpful trick

```
private void save(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".png";
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(), bitmap, imageFileName, null);
    Uri uriimage = Uri.parse(path);
    // you made it, make  fun
    }
```

But this have a drawback i.e. you cant change the Directory it always save images to Pictures directory but if you got it fixed fill free to edit my code:
Haa-ha-ha {I can't use emojis with my keyboard}, Good Day

Comment: Don't forgot to give permissions else probability of down vote increases for my post

Answer (score 0):

Following are fixes i found
first add these two lines in your AndroidManifest file

Than add the below line just after setContentView method

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FullImageActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_CODE);
```

and for saving the images in gallery use the below code

```
private void SaveImageToGallery() {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/folderName");
        dir.mkdirs();
        String filename = String.format("%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis());
        File outfile = new File(dir,filename);
        try{
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("SavingError", "SaveImageToGallery: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved in folderName folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: and What about Gif and Animated Webp. these types will be converted into static images

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any numbers in the filename, it should work, but I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).