# How to read file contents?

Tags: android

I am trying below code to select pdf from directory and read its contents but its not working

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(requestCode) {
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
//                    String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
//                    textViewFilePath.setText("File : " + filePath);
//                    readFromPdf(filePath);

                    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                    String filePath = data.getDataString();
                    try {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
                        String line;

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            text.append(line);
                            text.append('n');
                        }
                        scanResults.setText(text + ".....");
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

I am getting below exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2295: open
>   failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36213976/9130109

Answer (score 1):

You should open an InputStream like

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

You should not try to use a reader or try to read lines.

Those do not make sense for a pdf file.

Comment: Will you please provide complete answer? I am badly stuck in this

Comment: What is it that you are missing?

Comment: I need to get file path. Current commented one is wrong

Comment: Even if there was a file path then the rest of your code is nonsense as you cannot use a FileReader and read lines for a pdf file. It is unclear what you try to accomplisch.

Comment: Will you please let me know why it says ioexception for file path

Comment: I need to get filepath for the selected file

Comment: It is no file path that you use. You got a content scheme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165426/discussion-between-vvb-and-greenapps).

Comment: Sorry. No chat.

Comment: @VVB no, you dont need a filepath, you need  `InputStream`

Comment: If i read by inputstream then it prints diamonds I need clear text

Comment: You still dont realise you cant use readers. And cannot read lines from a pdf file? Well you cant. You should come up with something different to read the content of a pdf file. You want to read the pictures in it with lines too?

Comment: What changes should I need to make in my code then?

Comment: You have to change a lot. You cannot read the texts contained in a pdf document, text that is formatted and accompanied with pictures maybe with simple code. You need to code a pdf reader for that. No simple task.