# Android Q (10) ask permission to get access all storage. Scoped storage

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

In Android 10 apps that need to access storage need to ask permission to access a concrete path. But apps like file explorer can ask permission for access to the root storage and gain permission to read/write to all storage. That is what I am trying to do.

According to Android we must use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` for this. The problem I have is that everything seems correct, but the permission is not granted to the app.

```
  private void askAndroid10Perm()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        intent.addFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    }
```

Here the user can see Android file tree and, with main storage selected, click to grant permission. "It will allow - app name - to have full access to all files currently store under this location, and any future content stored here" -> Allow

Then:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri treeUri = data.getData();
                int takeFlags = data.getFlags();
                takeFlags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                    Log.i("TAG", "takePersistableUriPermission: " + treeUri);
                    this.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);

                }

            }
    }
}
```

Log:

> takePersistableUriPermission:
>   content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A

Then the app will still not have permission to access to root.

> open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Of course I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Granted by the user.

Comment: I don't think you can have root access in Android Q

Comment: Some apps that I tested have this access with scoped storage. For example "Solid explorer" app.

Comment: Yes, I know. I had asked a similar question and CommonWare said to me that that is because of the engineers those companies have. I know, his answer wasn't that useful.

Comment: what do you mean with root access?

Comment: Access to device storage files. Same files that show default file explorer preinstalled app. I am not talking about system root files. Root dir of mounted devices, external sd card and internal storage.

Comment: You can do it but you didn't show in the question how you are trying to "open" the root. You can use DocumentFile class and then use list files.

Answer (score 42):

Add line in Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" //Add this Line
    android:label="@string/app_name">

---------<Activity, Sevices or Recivers>----------

</application>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: This is only temporarily, see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage

Comment: Well that just cost me 3 hours of my life... Thanks D_K

Comment: In android 11 It will not work anymore. So, How can we access full storage access on android 11 too? any idea?

Comment: You have to use MediaStore for Android 11 or above

look out this : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

Answer (score 14):

you must add this line in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem was that I use File object to access files, but permission only work if we use DocumentFile object to manipulate files.

Solved using DocumentFile instead of File.

It has multiple negative points to use DocumentFile, such as performance and that you don't have access to apache commons libraries for example, but there is no other option.

Comment: does File(path), file.delete(), mkdirs() not work on android Q? What does scoped storage change?

Comment: There are libs for java that you can copy, cut or zip directories in "File" objects for example. This libs not exist for DocumentFile.

Comment: File API is not available in android 10 for files in shared storage that your app does not own. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths

Answer (score 1):

It could be simpler with [Simple Storage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage). You can request the storage full access to the user:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val storageHelper = SimpleStorageHelper(this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnRequestStorageAccess.setOnClickListener {
            storageHelper.requestStorageAccess()
        }

        storageHelper.onStorageAccessGranted = { requestCode, root ->
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

It works on Android 10 and higher. No need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

(NOT WORKING ON ANDROID 11)add this in your manifest file in the application so your application will be as follow :

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

for android 11 I did like this

```
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(mContext);
String fullPath =cw.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString();
File directory = cw.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
```

check it here https://www.programmersought.com/article/50766505696/