# Android: Button clicked but Method did not start

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-camera, android-image

Hello I am trying to create a little Activity which has a Button, two TextViews and a ImageView. The Activity should send a Intent for capturing a Photo and saving the Photo in cache, when the button has been clicked.

**SOLVED current Error can be found under EDIT:**

The Problem is, that when I hit the button, nothing happens. After adding some Logs I found out, that the Problem is in the following Method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "target");
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );

    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

It is the example for saving a Image from the Developer Documentation but I changed the code here:

```
File storageDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "export");
```

To get around the FileProvider Error.

Does somebody know what is wrong with my code?

**EDIT**: For the Solution of the Error above follow the link from Rahul.
        Now I get another Problem with the FileProvider.

**SOLVED see Ajith Pandians Answer for Solution**

```
    Logcat:

    09-15 10:44:31.551 14882-14882/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.NftSimple E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.artoolkit.ar.samples.NftSimple, PID: 14882
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.NftSimple/cache/targets/JPEG_20160915_104431_363552678.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:678)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:377)
    at org.artoolkit.ar.samples.nftSimple.MenuActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MenuActivity.java:72)
    at org.artoolkit.ar.samples.nftSimple.MenuActivity.access$000(MenuActivity.java:27)
    at org.artoolkit.ar.samples.nftSimple.MenuActivity$1.onClick(MenuActivity.java:46)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And the Code that uses the File Provider:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Log.i(TAG, "I try to use my Method");
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error while creating the Image: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "org.artoolkit.ar.samples.nftSimple.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<cache-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.nftSimple/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Provider in Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="org.artoolkit.ar.samples.nftSimple.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole error log that you get when that method is called?

Comment: @Aenadon Totally forgot that. Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem on file_paths.xml file.

By the document

```
    <cache-path name="name" path="path" />
   "Represents files in the cache subdirectory of your app's internal storage area.  
   The root path of this subdirectory is the same as the value returned by getCacheDir()".
```

means it will return "/data/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.nftSimple/cache/".

You just need to give subfolder like "pictures/" to get 
"Android/data/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.nftSimple/cache/pictures/".

Your file_paths.xml should like this

```
  <cache-path name="my_images" path="target/" />
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but thats what also Rahul mentioned in his Answer through the Link

Comment: see my edited answer and let me know the result. @Vincentthe0ne

Answer (score 1):

try to add the folowing in your AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

also possible solution for your problem is this:

[Error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, but I already got it in my manifest.

Comment: According to the Android documentation, you don't need permission for saving to cache directory. --> "Apps require no extra permissions to read or write to the returned path [the cache path], since this path lives in their private storage."

Comment: You are not using Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES correctly. It is not a folder by itself, you need to use it as a parameter to getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() method. 
Check here : [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

Comment: And for Marhsmallow devices, make sure Contacts Groups Permissions is granted too by device user.
Ref: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Rahul Khurana Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES and Contacts were never mentioned in this question....

Comment: @Rahul Khurana ok, that solved the "No such File or directory" Problem, but now the FileProvider seems to throw Errors I update my Question with the LogCat and Code

Comment: @Rahul Khurana updated the Question under **EDIT:** is the issue i get now **Note:** I still use the cache Directory and not the External with Environment.PICTURE. Even though both seem to produce the same erorr

Comment: hey @Vincentthe0ne can  you provide the log value for **storageDir** when you are going to create temp file

Comment: @Rahul Khurana `09-15 10:59:36.392 15389-15389/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.NftSimple I/MenuActivity: StorageDir: /data/data/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.NftSimple/cache/targets`