# File Not Found with Firebase - App closes as soon as it starts

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

First of all, this is not a duplicate of [Error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory) I have been through this.

Second: Please read the whole question.

Third: The error was not in my code. I had to remove all filters from logcat and see this error.

This is strange, I was developing this app and using it until yesterday. Right now when I launched it on my device from Android Studio I see this error. When I remove the code that handles firebase auth and firebase UI this the error goes away.

Also, I don't know if it is related but, I had to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio and all SDKs this morning, I am facing this error after that.

I have looked at almost every resource out there, on StackOverflow and multiple gists on GitHub but none of them helped.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank in advance.

```
12-26 12:17:50.061 1207-1315/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime
                                                         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                             at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8862)
                                                             at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1685)
                                                             at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:232)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                             at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                             at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8862) 
                                                             at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1685) 
                                                             at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:232) 
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                             at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I have required permission to read and write in manifest too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Which part of it? @NiravJoshi.
The error is not linked with my code. Its an internal error most probably.

Comment: @Nilu This is not a duplicate of the question linked by you. Please read my question properly. I have been through that post before and it dd not help.

Comment: @AbhinavUpadhyay read your error `Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT`

Comment: Do you have storage permissions for your app?

Comment: @CoolGuyCG Yes. I'll update the question with permission from my manifest.

Comment: What I meant was, have you given it access in case you are using an android API 23+ device

Comment: @Nilu I read it. The error name is same. The link mentioned by you it happens because someone was trying to make a directory without making sure it was there or not. In my case I am not handling any directory or images. It is happening because of firebase or firebase-ui but I am not sure how. I have been through the link provided by you. Nothing addresses my issue. Please compare both the questions and if you have a solution please hit me with it.

Comment: @CoolGuyCG yes, I have given it access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. For the newbies out there. The error occurred because of unstable network.

I dont know why the FileNotFound Error was thrown though. But I tested the same thing on five different devices and finally, only this makes sense. When I moved to a better internet connection the error seemed to resolve itself.

Hope this saves someone else's time.

Comment: this seems weird to me - i'm pretty sure i'm having stable connection, but i'm having this error as well. No crash reports in console (i've waited for some two hours, let's see tomorrow)

Comment: @Antek try on a different connection if it helps then it's it might be an issue from firebase

Comment: ah, sorry for not updating - it turned out that some remainders of fabric (which i migrated from) caused this bug to appear. Solved

Comment: no it's not you should fix the problem with that device if you try more than 5 devices you can fall into the problem again and again i'm still searching for a solution but didn't find

Comment: @Faridomastr I never saw the problem again so couldn't ever debug it. But please let me know if you find a solution. I'll update the accepted answer