# Generate Pdf and save in a particular folder in Android

Tags: android, file, pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF and Save it to particular folder and open it after the PDF is generated successfully.But I am getting some exceptions

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/PDF/demo.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have also tried this [solution](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-generate-pdf-documents-for-your-android-application-8abd3de7fe3b) but it didn't Work out

The Code I have tried as below:

```
 private void cretaePDF() {

        Document doc = new Document();
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            Log.d("PDFCreater", "PDF Path" + path);

            File file = new File(dir, "demo.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fout);
            doc.open();
            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi, Its me");
            doc.add(p1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And for opening the PDF is:

```
 private void openPDF() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";
        File file = new File(path, "demo.pdf");
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application.pdf");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

What and where is the mistake?

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();`. Check the return value. And do not continue if it fails but display a toast to the user and return.

Comment: When do you get that exception? And how do you know that a file is generated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file); this line is throwing me the error.I think the file is not getting created

Comment: Refer this :- http://www.androhub.com/android-download-files-save/

Comment: @avik have you given `runtime permission ?`

Comment: make sure your have given WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: Yes I have solved the issue.yes I have added the permission