# i want to download a image from network but give this Exception :android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

[image]I put permissions in Manifest.
I want to download an image from the internet and store it in external storage.
Image link is okay.
There is a problem writing external memory.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final static String DL_URL = "https://download.hipwallpaper.com/desktop/1920/1080/1/97/yE0qUN.jpg";
    public static Context context;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},111);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute(DL_URL);

    }


class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int lenghtfile = connection.getContentLength();

            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());  //
            File dir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getParent());
            File myDir = new File(dir,"Downloads");
            File outFile = new File(myDir,"yE0qUN.jpg");
            outFile.mkdirs();


            byte[] myfile = new byte[lenghtfile];

            input.read(myfile);

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            output.write(myfile);
            output.flush();
            output.close();


        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share exception stacktrace.

Comment: Yes, Sure.
I put his picture.

Comment: are you sure you have GRANTED the **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission before doing `task.execute(DL_URL);` ? Please confirm from App Settings

Comment: yes i sure. i check that with: onRequestPermissionsResult().

what is the App Settings?

Comment: Make sure the Downloads directory exists.
    myDir.mkdirs();

Comment: directory is not  exists.But I don't know why!

Comment: it means you need to create it by `myDir.mkdirs();`

Comment: I did it.
  But myDir is not exists.

Comment: chek this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: The title of your post is wrong. You want to create a directory and a file. You can remove all download code as it is irrelevant. Start with checking the return value of mkdirs() and do not continue if it fails.

Comment: Yet better care for a directory before you start the asynctask.

Comment: Further your directory path is not available on Android Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was always creating directories.
In fact, I didn't create the file in the directory.
Now I created a directory and set the path for my new file.
I modified the above code as below and the problem was resolved:

```
File dir = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+"Downloads"));  

 dir.mkdirs();

 File outFile = new File(dir,"wallpaper.png");
```