# How to send file with retrofit2 to server

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm having difficulties with sending an audio file with retrofit2. I get `file: 'okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part@8f3c9ed'`. How can I send file in request.file, not in request.body? Also how can I send it as file (with properties like originalname, buffer, etc)? Here is my code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("audio/upload")
    fun uploadAudio(
        @Part("file") file: MultipartBody.Part,
        @Field("title") title: String,
        @Field("description") description: String,
        @Field("writer") writer: String,
        @Field("privacy") privacy: Int,
        @Field("duration") duration: Int,
        @Field("secretLink") secretLink: String,
        @Field("isForKids") isForKids: Boolean,
        @Field("language") language: String,
        @Field("tags") tags: List<Tag>,
    ): Call<Any>
```

Here I call it:

```
    private fun uploadAudio() {
        val sharedPreferences = context?.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        if (title == null) {
            return Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Title is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        if (description == null) {
            return Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Description is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        if (newAudio == null) {
            return Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Audio file is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        mainContent.visibility = GONE
        newAudioProgressBar.visibility = VISIBLE

        submitButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.upload_avd, 0)
        val avdSubmitButton = submitButton.compoundDrawables[2] as AnimatedVectorDrawable
        avdSubmitButton.start()

        val inputStream = context?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(Uri.parse(newAudio))
        val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/mpeg"), File(newAudio))
        val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", title, requestFile)

        RetrofitService().uploadAudio(
            body,
            title!!,
            description!!,
            sharedPreferences?.getString("token", null).toString(),
            privacy!!,
            audioDuration!! / 1000,
            secretLink.text.toString(),
            forKids!!,
            language!!,
            tagAdapter.tags
        ).enqueue(object : Callback<Any> {
            @SuppressLint("LogNotTimber")
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
                d("#Error", "${t.message}")
                mainContent.visibility = VISIBLE
                newAudioProgressBar.visibility = GONE

                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            @SuppressLint("LogNotTimber")
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Any>, response: Response<Any>) {
                navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.myAudiosFragment)
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Audio uploaded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }
```

When I try `File(newAudio)`, it says it can't find a file. newAudio equals `audio.path`.

Comment: what is the path of the audio file?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar, /document/primary:Music/Track28.mp3

Comment: This file exists, but it says ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @dinkar_kumar, what is it?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar, I don't want to create a new file, I want to take an existing one from a device.