# Open camera using Jetpack compose Button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to open the camera using a button, but I'm not getting it how do I make this button work? I Tried to declare it in variable but it's not working either.

```
package com.example.bohubrihiwithjetpack

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.bohubrihiwithjetpack.compose.LearningCompose

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

        }
    }

    fun checkCameraPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            openCamera()
        } else {
            requestPermission()
        }
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
            1
        )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }


    fun openCamera() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

And This is the Compose Code, also I don't understand how this Compose works Like there is no id like XML. How do I make the widget work?

```
package com.example.bohubrihiwithjetpack.compose

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import com.example.bohubrihiwithjetpack.MainActivity
import java.util.jar.Manifest

@Composable
fun LearningCompose(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current


    Column {
        Button(onClick = { MainActivity().checkCameraPermission() }, modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Open Camera")
        }
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Open Gallery")
        }

        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Open Browser")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this doesn't work because you're creating a new activity inside your composable. Check out [How to get activity in compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675386/how-to-get-activity-in-compose)

Comment: Also you don't actually need an activity here at all, check out how to use [Compose CameraX on Android](https://proandroiddev.com/compose-camerax-on-android-58578f37e6df)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory