# Why does assets images directory contain files which i did not put in there at design time?

Tags: java, android, android-assets, enoent

I'm still a beginner in Android. Be cool please :)
I'm trying to insert 1 picture from my asset directory but I have a problem.
Here is my code to insert my picture :

```
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/images");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();



        Log.i("HINT",imagesFolder.getAbsolutePath());

        String[] images = null;

        try {
            images = assetManager.list("images");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
        }
        for(String filename : images) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open("images/"+filename);
                File outFile = new File(imagesFolder, filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }
        }
```

I have only 1 picture in my assetFolder (dataset12soleil), but it looks like my method is looking for other files that I don't even know:

```
E/tag: Failed to copy asset file: clock_font.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/images/clock_font.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at com.example.testbackup.ui.dataset1.Dataset1Fragment.copyAssets(Dataset1Fragment.java:111)
        at com.example.testbackup.ui.dataset1.Dataset1Fragment.access$400(Dataset1Fragment.java:58)
        at com.example.testbackup.ui.dataset1.Dataset1Fragment$1.onClick(Dataset1Fragment.java:247)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7157)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:821)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27660)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7460)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
        at com.example.testbackup.ui.dataset1.Dataset1Fragment.copyAssets(Dataset1Fragment.java:111) 
        at com.example.testbackup.ui.dataset1.Dataset1Fragment.access$400(Dataset1Fragment.java:58) 
        at com.example.testbackup.ui.dataset1.Dataset1Fragment$1.onClick(Dataset1Fragment.java:247) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7157) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:821) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27660) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994) 
E/tag: Failed to copy asset file: dataset12soleil.jpg
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/images/dataset12soleil.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)


...

E/tag: Failed to copy asset file: android-logo-shine.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/images/android-logo-shine.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
E/tag: Failed to copy asset file: android-logo-mask.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/images/android-logo-mask.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Well I just want to keep my picture and delete others where can I find them ? :(

Inside of my asset folder :
[my image directory inside of my asset folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weGqe.png)

EDIT :
Finally, i tried to rename my folder "asset/images" into "asset/test" and it's working. I only have my picture and not the others.
[This just helped me to find the solution](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/assets/images/)

Comment: On which line you are getting this exception?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @QandilTariq on this line  :  File outFile = new File(imagesFolder, filename);

Comment: Dont tell that you cannot find a file in assets if the problem is that you cannot create a file. Please change subject of your post.

Comment: `imagesFolder.mkdirs();` Only use mkdirs() if  the direwctory does not exist yet. if ( !imagesFolder.exists()) { if (!imagesFolder.mkdirs()) { Toast (..sorry could not create directory ..) return;} }. I bet that the directory cannot be created.

Comment: File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/images");
get the file folder in same way.

Comment: @blackapps I don't want to create file, you did not understand what i was looking for.
 I just want to know where the other files are coming from

Comment: Better: `File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "images");`

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(outFile);` That creates a file! Well it tries. But it fails with: `FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/images/clock_font.png` But you have no directory `images` yet for it and you arte unaware of this missing directory.

Comment: @blackapps I don't want to create a file for "clock_font.ong"  I just want to knwo where is come from, I don't have it in my asst folder so how this error can appear

Comment: Your reactions dont make sense. As you wanna copy a file from assets to external storage. So you wanna create a file on external storage. And the exception is telling you that you cannot create that file.

Comment: @blackapps You just don't understand it dude, my current problem is : some files are not in my asset folder but they my metod try to insert them, but where they are come from ?

Comment: Are you tying to insert files in assets at runtime? You did not tell that before. And which files? How would we know which files you have in mind? Or where they would come from? The code you posted code is for copying a file from assets to external storage.

Comment: @blackapps I just edited my post, look my asset folder. I have 1 file(dataset12soleil). But where is clock-font.png ?? I don't want it, I just want to delete it, but I can't find it. Why ?

Comment: Delete? I read: `I'm trying to insert 1 picture from my asset directory ` And I cannot see what you have in your assets folder. And if fileName equals clock-font.png than you put that in your code.

Comment: I know I am copying files to external storage.
I explained in my post that I was looking to copy only 1 files.
And I also said that I didn't understand where the others were coming from.
I read : **I have only 1 picture in my assetFolder (dataset12soleil), but it looks like my method is looking for other files that I don't even know**
and I read too : **Well I just want to keep my picture and delete others where can I find them ?**

Comment: Sorry dude if it's still not clear, but the problem is that I don't have clock_font.png in my code or in my asset folder and I would like to understand why

Comment: Well, I find something, I the names of myfolder is "images" my method will try to insert automatically some othes files. But if called it "test" it's ok. All is good but I still don't undertsant why "asset/images" is special. @blackapps, I find this : [link] (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/assets/images/) I don't know if this can help you too but well. Have a nice day

Comment: Hé hé. Your code tries to list the files in an 'images' directory in assets. Maybe you put a file in assets/images at design time. But even if you had not created that images directory yourself that directory would still have been there at runtime. They are just system images. You could also try to list files in assets webkit directory.

Comment: `Files not found in asset directory` A very confusing subject. Better: why does assets images directory contain files which i did not put in there at design time?

Comment: Ok thank you for this explanation @blackapps.
I just edited the subject too, thank you :)

Comment: Well done! And i like the 'Better:' ;-).

Comment: @blackapps it's a dedication ;-)