# Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**Getting that error:**

```
Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: '/storage/emulated/0/meusarquivos/dd.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)'
```

**on this line (SaveAndView method):**

```
var outs = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

**SaveAndView:**

```
public void SaveAndView(string fileName, string contentType, MemoryStream stream)
        {
            try
            {
                string root = null;
                //Get the root path in android device.
                root = Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageEmulated ? Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString() : System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

                //Create directory and file 
                var myDir = new Java.IO.File(root + "/meusarquivos");
                myDir.Mkdir();

                var file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, fileName);

                //Remove if the file exists
                if (file.Exists()) file.Delete();

                //Write the stream into the file
                var outs = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outs.WriteAsync(stream.ToArray());

                outs.Flush();
                outs.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
                //PostLog.AppCenterLogExcecao(ex, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "origem", "OrderViewModel - 159" } });
            }
        }
```

**My AndroidManifest.xml looks as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.mobileappxamarinbarcodescanner">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:label="MobileAppXamarinBarcodeScanner.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

**What am i missing?**

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that you delete the file in the line above the line causing the error........ You need to create the file again before doing anything with it. Did you mean to say "fileName" instead of "file"?

Comment: @squidwardsface u mean this could be to the facto i delete file and this could be issue? If I just remote that deletion line would the file be append each try?

Comment: @squidwardsface i removed the line which checks and delte the file nevertheless i get same error

Comment: I'd suggest using System.IO classes for doing this instead of the Java classes

Comment: @Jason can u post example as an answer ?

Comment: Google search for the error message shows MANY previous questions. Here is one: [Error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088699/error-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory). In your code, make sure the folder exists. And make sure you have asked for android permission to create files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `System.IO` to achieve this instead of Java classes.

I created a simple demo to achieve this,and it works.

You can refer to the following code:

```
  using System.IO;

  public void SaveAndView(string fileName)
  {
      try
      {

          string text = "hello world";
          byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

          string rootPath = Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageEmulated ? Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString() : System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
          var filePathDir = Path.Combine(rootPath, "meusarquivos");
          if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePathDir))
          {
              Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathDir);
          }
          string filePath = Path.Combine(filePathDir, fileName);

          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("filePath  is:" + filePath);
          System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);


      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
  }
```

Usage:

```
 SaveAndView("dd.pdf");
```

And you can refer to the official sample here:   [LocalFiles](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/LocalFiles).

For more detail, you can check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows .

Comment: @Arie - notice how this answer has logic to create directory if it does not exist.